# Creating my own REST API throws servlet execution exception

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, exception, servlets

I have been working on my own REST API built with jersey and java. Today it stopped working though after a friend who also works on it pushed his changes. he didn't change anything on the dependency side, but he did add an controller that our main API class creates. Now whenever I try to reach a resource the tomcat server throws an error:

```
    exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
    javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:669)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.ja
```

We belive it started after he added jsoup dependency.

EDIT:
I edited my dependencies and web.xml, and now I only get 404 not found.

This is my dependencies form my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
           <version>2.23.2</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
             <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
             <version>1.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>[4.0,)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.facebook4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>facebook4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>[2.4,)</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>api</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Edit
If I try to reach: http://localhost:8080/api-mashup-api/api/v1/foobar

```
@Path("/v1")
public class API {
private Controller controller;

public API(){
    controller = new Controller();
}


/**
 * Prints to the screen if we are in /v1/foobar
 * 
 * @return
 */
@GET
@Path("/foobar")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String print2() {
    return "Please specify what resource you need.";
}
```

I just get 404.

Comment: share code please

Comment: share code and more info

Comment: `Now whenever I try to reach a resource`: how is your resource configured? What is the URI you're trying to reach? And what do you mean by `controller`?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your issue caused by wrong  **jersey-container-servlet** which may cause the wrong uribuilder to be pickedup

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html#server-jdk

**jersey-container-servlet**    => Jersey core Servlet 3.x implementation

**jersey-container-servlet-core** =>    Jersey core Servlet 2.x implementation

Change:

```
<dependency>
           <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
           <version>2.23.2</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
           <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
           <version>2.23.2</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Also refer https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html#dependencies to find out which dependencies you need to provide for Glassfish and other Servlet based (non jax-rs integrated) containers

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You have an `AbstractMethodError` exception which is thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method.
`uri` is an abstract method in `UriBuilder`, so you need an implementation of this.

You should use JAX-RS 2.0 with Jersey 2.* that implements JAX-RS 2.0 and contains an implementation to `uri` method.

**2)** By looking at your stack trace it clearly states that you are using both Jersey versions 1 & 2 and that's not possible, So the classloader is picking up the wrong URIBuilder class.

**Stack Trace:**

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:669)
```

The Jersey dependencies in group `com.sun.jersey` are all Jersey version 1.  Jersey version 2 uses the group `org.glassfish.jersey`.

Comment: As you can see in my edit, I have fixed that, now I just get 404. I might add that we used jersey 1.x before but changed to 2.23.2 yesterday and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, I can see that but your changes are not reflected yet. There are some linkages to jersey 1 jars from your project. need to do some cleanup, delete the jersey 1 jars if exists from the location where maven have downloaded it. Otherwise create a new project and copy paste your code bases.